# Prove that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x\}$ is a closed in $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the usual metric.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know the set is closed if it is the complement of an open set and I know the definition of usual metric. But I don't know how to prove this question.

Comment: So ... you need to show the complement of $\{x\}$ is open.  What is that complement?  What is the definition of "open"?

Comment: What is the complement of $\{x\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: **(-∞,x)∪(x,∞)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\} = (-\infty, x)\cup (x, \infty)$ is a union of open sets.

Comment: Thanks, but the examples I looked at were like (3,7), (2,4) etc. I don't know how to prove it when it's ∞ in it.

Comment: Write $(x,\infty)=(x,x+2)\cup (x+1,x+3)\cup (x+2,x+4)\cup (x+3,x+5)\ldots$ and $(-\infty, x)=(x-2,x)\cup (x-3,x-1)\cup (x-4,x-2)\cup (x-5,x-3)\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

If the set $\{x\}$ is a closed set, then it is equivalent to prove $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$ is open. To show this, you can show that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}, \exists \epsilon > 0 \ni B(y, \epsilon) \cap \{x\} = \emptyset$. I'll leave the rest to you, since this shouldn't be hard to show. Thus, since $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$ is open, then $\{x\}$ is closed.